# using a variable from a method of another class in python

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, tuples

I have code that goes like this:

```
class A(object):  
    def __init__(self, master):  
        """Some work here"""  

    def do_this(self):  
        self.B = B.do_that()  
        print self.B[1]  


class B(object):  
    def __init__(self, master):  
        """Some work here"""  

    def do_that(self):  
        p = (1, 2)
```

I can't make the method in class A to use that self.B as a tuple. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `do_that()` doesn't return anything. So calling it will pretty much do nothing.

`self.B = B.do_that()` also won't work. You have to first create an instance of the class `B`:

```
mything = B(your_parameters)
mything.do_that()
```

And if you want that to return something (i.e, the tuple), you should change your `do_that()` to:

```
def do_that(self):  
    return (1, 2)
```

One final note, this can all be achieved through Inheritance:

```
class A(B): # Inherits Class B
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Some work here""" 
    def do_this(self):
        print self.do_that()[1] # This is assuming the do_that() function returns that tuple
```

Using the inheritance method:

```
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self, master):
...         """Some work here"""
...     def do_that(self):
...         return (1,2)
... 
>>> class A(B):
...     def __init__(self, master):
...         """Some work here"""
...     def do_this(self):
...         print self.do_that()[1] 
...
>>> mything = A('placeholder')
>>> mything.do_this()
2
```

Comment: yeah okay. thank you. I wont use inheritance though, because I have to inherent from frame/object for this assignment.

Comment: @user2372332 Ah okay, so probably the other suggestions will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to instantiate B as a property of A in the method `A.do_this()`.
The following code should work.

```
def do_this(self):
    b = B()
    self.B = b.do_that()  
    print self.B[1]
```